# Opcache and shared memory issue

Tags: linux

I installed zend_opcache on my server box , but I can not increase opcache.memory_consumption over 1600 . (example : 2048) . after increase following error occur in server :

```
Fatal Error Fatal Error Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 2147483648 bytes: mmap: No space left on device (28)Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 2147483648 bytes: mmap: No space left on device
```

any idea ?

Comment: You are on a 32-bit system, you need to be using a 64-bit system.

Comment: Our Server 64bit system.